# Error with a function declaration constructor (Type provides no match for the signature 'new') [TypeScript]

Tags: typescript

I'm a TS beginner and I got a problem with Construct Signatures.
I have a constructor function `foo` which produces an object with 1 property and I want to pass this constructor to `fn` function which will run the passed constructor with a `new` operator.

But I got an error `"Type '(name: string) => void' provides no match for the signature 'new (name: string): NewObject'."` on the last line. How could I handle it? Should I always use a `class` for it?

```
type NewObject = {
  name: string;
}

type NewConstructor = {
  new (name: string): NewObject;
};

function fn(ctor: NewConstructor) {
  return new ctor('John');
}

function foo(name: string) {
  this.name = name;
};

fn(foo); // Error
```

I used [TS Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures), but there is no usage example.

Comment: "Should I always use a `class` for it?"  [Yes](https://tsplay.dev/wE8gvW).  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?